# How to copy multiple ".gz" files from the sub directories to one directory by grepping a keyword?

Tags: command-line

I would need a command to copy the files from multiple directories  to one directory (/home/c/) which are all having "ZA*3094~". Note that files are in compressed format (gz).

Example:
/home/a/20180901/file.gz
/home/a/20180902/file1.gz
/home/a/20180903/file2.gz
/home/a/20180903/file3.gz

Comment: I believe the `zgrep` command can help

Answer (score 0):

The `zgrep` command should help, I have this example

```
mv $(find a/*/* -type f -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -l 'nob' {} \;) /tmp
```

The command does the following:

- `zgrep` like `grep` uses the `-l` option to return the filenames that contain the search word `nob`
- `mv $(find a/*/* -type f -name "*.gz" -exec zgrep -l 'nob' {} \;) /tmp` will move any returned files with extension `.gz` to the `/tmp` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foor loop

`IFS=$'\n'; for i in $( find <source_directory> -type f | grep '.gz$'); do echo cp \"$i\" \"<destination_directory>\"; done`

replace `<source_directory>` and `<destination_directory>`

- IFS will prevent splitting paths containing a space into multiple lines
- find with `-type f` will only return files
- grep will filter for files ending with `.gz`
- `echo` for a dryrun, If everything looks ok just remove the echo

Comment: How is the grepping done in your script?

Comment: The output of find is piped to grep

Comment: The grepping should be for files of type `gz` that have a pattern in them, that's what I meant